# Opening a Chrome:// protocol link from Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

As far as I can tell, only a Bookmark, or a location bar input can open a `chrome://` link.

For example, if you click on chrome://chrome-urls from this post, in Chrome, it won't open.

Is there any way I can open a `chrome://` protocol link from a webpage, such as Javascript or XHR's?

Comment: No. It's the intended limit. Only a chrome extension can do it.

Comment: Allowing it from XHR would let the website get your bookmarks, preferences, etc. Do you really think that should be allowed?

Comment: @Barmar correct. I'm working to secure a Chrome cluster and wanted to ensure that Bookmarks and Navigation events are the only ways to open these links.